# Adding an onclick function to radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to add a click function to radio button, that I have given an id of flow. When the radio button is checked, a sample paragraph should be displayed, but for some reason it is not working. I know my Javascript click function works because I've tested it with `alert()`.

Comment: Please post the code relevant to your question.

Comment: So far, I have the impression you can achieve the wanted result with a css-only solution. But I need your code sample to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

for Radio you can use a "change" event using "class" or Input "Name" for both instead of id. please refer a below

```
Using Input Name:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:radio[name=inputName]').change(function() {
        alert('Radio Change')
    });
});

Using Input ClassName:
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.YourClassName').change(function() {
        alert('Radio Change')
    });
});
```

Comment: no evidence that he uses jquery and I suspect that the problem is at his display function since alert() works.